# add 'x' colors to button border with onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm actually trying to add a color to a part of my border button in 'x' times. So far, I managed to get my initial border with my first `click` function. Now I woud like to modify the color only on the half, 1/3, 1/4... of the border.

The princip that I'm looking for is : Every time, I'll click on the buttons it'll add a "lvl" to the button. And to show that, modify a bit the border. The last "lvl" would fill border.

I've two problems. 1st, except by using the `border-top-color`, `border-left-color`, `border-right-color` and `border-bottom-color`, I don't find a solution to split the color filling and it limits me to quarter only.

I also could use the `:after` and `:before` to change them, but it seems that I'm struggling a lot with those.

2nd, it seems that my second `js` function, that I've copied on the 1st one doesn't work. I think it's because of the `var` declaration. I know the `skill_unlocked` class is not directly written in my HTML code but just add after. Does it block the function to start ?

EDIT : I've try to modify the `js` with :

```
if document.getElementsByClassName("btn").hasClass("skill_unlocked") {
document.getElementsByClassName("skill_unlocked").addEventListener("click", function() {
 this.classList.add("skill_lvl_1");
});
```

It seems to cancel the first function.

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.add("skill_unlocked");
  });
}

/* WORKS TOO (SIMPLIFIED METHOD?)
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {
  $(this).addClass('skill_unlocked');
}); */

var skill_unlocked = document.getElementsByClassName("skill_unlocked");

for (var i = 0; i < skill_unlocked.length; i++) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("skill_unlocked")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.add("skill_lvl_1");
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #575757;
}

.btn {
  margin: 10px;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.6;
  border: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  outline: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
}

.fas {
  font-size: 28px;
}

.skill_unlocked {
  border: 2px solid white;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
}

.skill_lvl_1 {
  border: 2px solid;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
  border-top-color:green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="button border.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <button class="btn"><i class=" fas fa-shipping-fast fa-inverse"></i></button>
  <button class="btn"><i class=" fas fa-address-card fa-inverse"></i></button>
  <button class="btn"><i class=" fas fa-camera-retro fa-inverse"></i></button>
  <button class="btn"><i class="fas fa-flag fa-inverse"></i></button>
  <button class="btn"></button>
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="button border.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume you want to color the top-right-bot-left border (in that order) for each click after the white border, if that right then you can check this code

```css
body {
  background-color: #575757;
}

.btn {
  margin: 10px;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.6;
  border: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  outline: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
}

.fas {
  font-size: 28px;
}

.skill_unlocked {
  border: 2px solid white;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
}

.skill_lvl_1 {
  border: 2px solid;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
  border-top-color:green;
}

.skill_lvl_2 {
  border: 2px solid;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
  border-top-color:green;
  border-right-color:green;
}

.skill_lvl_3 {
  border: 2px solid;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
  border-top-color:green;
  border-right-color:green;
  border-bottom-color:green;
}
.skill_lvl_4 {
  border: 2px solid;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
  border-top-color:green;
  border-right-color:green;
  border-bottom-color:green;
  border-left-color:green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="border.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <button class="btn"><i class=" fas fa-shipping-fast fa-inverse"></i></button>
  <button class="btn"><i class=" fas fa-address-card fa-inverse"></i></button>
  <button class="btn"><i class=" fas fa-camera-retro fa-inverse"></i></button>
  <button class="btn"><i class="fas fa-flag fa-inverse"></i></button>
  <button class="btn"></button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(this.classList.contains("skill_lvl_3"))
    this.classList.add("skill_lvl_4");
  else if(this.classList.contains("skill_lvl_2"))
    this.classList.add("skill_lvl_3");
  else if(this.classList.contains("skill_lvl_1"))
    this.classList.add("skill_lvl_2");
  else if(this.classList.contains("skill_unlocked"))
    this.classList.add("skill_lvl_1");
  else
     this.classList.add("skill_unlocked");
    });
  }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

i hope this is what you want to do

Comment: Perfect. For people interested : you can set `border-color` like this `border-color: green white white white;` to keep the "background"  border from `.skill_unlocked` class (ie: the 1st click). It may simplify your code.

Comment: yes, if you want to keep the white border then you can use that